# How to get unique array in Swift3.0

Tags: arrays, swift3, ios10

**Scene**, I've an array of `NSObject` class named `Comment` like `var comments:[Comment]?`. This class has property `commentBy`which is also a `NSObject` class named `User` and it has property to identify unique user which is `var key:String`.
*above description as code*,

```
class Comment:NSObject {
   var commentBy:User?
}
class User:NSObject {
   var key:String?
}
//In some other class
class someClass {
   var comments:[Comment]?
}
```

**What I want**
I want an unique array of Comment, suppose that `userA` has made 2 comments and `userB` has made 1 comment so there is three comments total, but **in my unique array, I want to show that two users made comments**.

what should I do?

Comment: Is this related to "NSSet" as mentioned in the title?

Comment: Why are Comment and User derived from `NSObject`? I think it would be much better to have them as `Structs`

Comment: Why is `commentBy` optional? Practically there aren't  comments without an author.

Comment: @vadian I imagine they are optional to get around the error of having no initialisers :D instead of creating the initialiser :)

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, most likely another *path-of-least-resistance-optional* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var comments: [Comment]?
let userKeys = comments?.flatMap { $0.commentBy?.key } ?? []
let set = Set(userKeys)
```

If all you want is the total number of unique user that have commented, then I think mapping comments to user's key then create a set of key is faster.

Answer (score 0):

See what i do, actually your question is `How to init a NSSet in swift` ?

```
class Comment:NSObject {
    var commentBy:User?
}
class User:NSObject {
    var key:String?
}
//In some other class
class someClass {
    var comments:[Comment]?
}

let user1 = User()
user1.key = "1"
let user2 = User()
user1.key = "2"

let c1 = Comment()
c1.commentBy = user1
let c2 = Comment()
c2.commentBy = user1
let c3 = Comment()
c3.commentBy = user2


let set: NSSet = [user1, user2]
let set2: NSSet = [user2]
set2.isSubset(of: set as! Set<AnyHashable>) //true

let set3: NSSet = [c1, c1]
set3.count //1
let set4: NSSet = [c1, c2, c3] // your unique array
let set5 = NSSet(array: [c1, c2, c1, c3])
set5.count //3
```

`set3` will always be `[c1]`, because the elements in `Set` or `NSSet` will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

First make `User` hashable in a way that makes them equal based on their unique key.

```
class User: NSObject
{
    let key:String

    init(key: String) { self.key = key }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool
    {
        guard let other = object as? User else { return false }
        return self.key == other.key
    }
    override var hashValue: Int { return key.hashValue }
}

let eq = User(key: "foo") == User(key: "foo") // true
let h1 = User(key: "foo").hashValue           // some big number
let h2 = User(key: "foo").hashValue           // same big number as above
```

I've made `key` immutable because, as it serves to uniquely identify a user, it should not be possible to change.

Because `User` is an `NSObject` it already has an implementation of `==` which uses `isEqual:` so you override that to compare based on the key. You also use the `hashValue` of `key` as the `User` hash value.

Now you can use `User` in sets and as keys in dictionaries. If you do the same for `Comment` so that they compare equal on `User` you can use comments in a set too. However, that is a bad idea. Two comments are not the same just because they have the same user. You should change `SomeClass` to use a dictionary keyed by user as follows:

```
class Comment: NSObject
{
    let user: User
    let text: String

    init(user: User, text: String)
    {
        self.user = user
        self.text = text
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    var userComments: [User : [Comment]] = [:]

    func addComment(newComment: Comment)
    {
        if let existingComments = userComments[newComment.user]
        {
            userComments[newComment.user] = existingComments + [newComment]
        }
        else
        {
            userComments[newComment.user] = [newComment]
        }
    }

    var userCount: Int { return userComments.count }
    var commentCount: Int { return userComments.values.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.count}) }
}
```

The property userCount is the number you asked for. The property commentCount is the total number of comments - although beware: the implementation runs in O(n) time. If speed is of the essence, you should maintain a counter that increments each time you add a comment.